# Equality and existence proof of a point in a triangle and its areas

Tags: plane-geometry

[image]
Can we always find a point $F$ in the line $BC$ of any triangle such as above so that the triangle $APQ$ is an isosceles triangle and the area of the triangle $AreaAPQ=AreaABC$?

It'll be grateful if someone could help me with this.

Given $AF$ is the angle bisector

Comment: Sure.  If $F=C$ the area is less (following your picture, in which $AC<AB$).  If $F=B$ the area is greater.  Don't see a classical construction instantly..but I expect there is one.

Comment: That proves that the point $F$ has to lie on the line $BC$ but how would we  prove that $F$ must lie on $BC$ and the angle bisector line simutaneously?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you wanted.  I thought you wanted an isosceles triangle with $F$ on the base.  You needed $F$ to be the midpoint of the base?

Comment: Would it be true if ,In other words we prove that $AreaFPC=AreaQFB$?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear.  Are you defining $F$ to be the intersection of the angle bisector and the segment $BC$?  That's not an existence question...$F$ clearly exists.  Of course you can then ask if $F$ has the property you want.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I wanted to know that if $AF$ is the height of the Isosceles triangle satisfying the simultaneity condition.

Comment: Yes I'm defining $F$ to be the intersection of the angle bisector to $BC$. And I wanted to know if it satifies the simultaneity condition that $AreaAPQ=AreaABC$

Comment: It's been so long I'm going over this diorama. I need some input. I'll appreciate it

Comment: I'm thinking about it.  Explicit examples are hard to draw...kind of interesting.  I'll post a solution if I find anything worth passing on.

Comment: Why brands with a slash CF and FB segments? This does mean that its are equal? If AF is the angle bisector it is not true.

Comment: Maybe I should change the picture

Comment: Well, do it. Regards.

Comment: Deleted slashs were for segments FQ and FP but it was a dispensable help for readers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always possible.

You need equality of areas of triangles $\triangle FQB$ and $\triangle FPC$. Let $\theta$ the angle $\angle QFB=\angle PFC$. Since $\overline{FQ}=\overline{FP}$ we have $$\frac 12 \overline{FB}\cdot\overline{FQ}\sin \theta=\frac 12 \overline{FC}\cdot\overline{FP}\sin \theta\iff\overline{FB}=\overline{FC}$$ which is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

hint....Since the area of the triangle is $$\frac 12bc\sin A=\frac 12|AP|^2\sin A$$ you have that $|AP|=|AQ|=\sqrt{bc}$

It therefore boils down to constructing the geometric mean of the two lengths $AB$ and $AC$ which is given here http://planetmath.org/compassandstraightedgeconstructionofgeometricmean So you can mark off the distances AP and AQ and thus find $F$

Comment: But are these conditions satisfied? $F$lies on $BC$ and $F$ lies on the angle bisector and also the area of Triangle ABC=APQ?

Comment: @Aretino thanks for spotting my silly typo. Much obliged.